# UnicodeDecodeError when starting brand new django project created with the tool

Tags: python, django, windows, encoding, django-admin

UPDATED: I downgraded from python 3.4 to 3.3.5 so Django is compatible with it, but the problem persists:

I am quite knew to python and django and I have installed python **3.3.5** and Django 1.6.6 in my Windows laptop. I am following django tutorial but I am stuck in the second step, because I am getting an error.

I created the project:

```
django-admin startproject TouristGuide
```

then I entered the created folder Tourist Guide where manage.py is located

```
cd TouristGuide
```

and then I start the server just as the tutorial suggests:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

and when I execute that line I get the following error:

```
Validating models...

0 errors found
September 01, 2014 - 23:11:07
Django version 1.6.6, using settings 'TouristGuide.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper
 at 0x02B4E9C0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 93, in w
rapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.
py", line 128, in inner_run
    ipv6=self.use_ipv6, threading=threading)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 167
, in run
    httpd = httpd_cls(server_address, WSGIRequestHandler, ipv6=ipv6)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 109
, in __init__
    super(WSGIServer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\socketserver.py", line 430, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 113
, in server_bind
    super(WSGIServer, self).server_bind()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 50, in server_bind
    HTTPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\http\server.py", line 137, in server_bind
    self.server_name = socket.getfqdn(host)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\socket.py", line 386, in getfqdn
    hostname, aliases, ipaddrs = gethostbyaddr(name)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe1 in position 4: invalid
continuation byte
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the name of my laptop was "Portátil" and when python uses gethostbyaddr its response has that name and it seems python doesn't handle the encoding correctly. I've changed the name of the laptop so now it doesn´t contain any accented character.